# Store inherited class object in codename one storage

Tags: java, storage, codenameone

I'm using the codenameone framework with java.
I've been a serious issue saving a List of a objects of a class farmer inheriting from a class Person. Both class implement the externalizable interface and i've correctly implemented the four required methods ( getVersion, externalize, internalize, getObjectId) in both classes too. I call super.initialize() as the first line of the initialize method in the farmer class and do the same thing for the externalize method too.

I can save a List  but i can't seem to read it from storage after closing and restarting the simulator. It just gives me a  list with first element being a Farmer but others elements being null.or Date values.

I've been seeking for solutions for this for several days. Any tip or advice would be really much appreciated from you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you implemented this method like that:

```
public String getObjectId() {
   return getClass().getName();
}
```

Instead of like this:

```
public String getObjectId() {
   return "MyObject";
}
```

You need to give a unique per object name for a class and need to have it hardcoded as class names might differ on the devices due to obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Shai. I already implemented the getObjectId method the way you suggested but i'm still having the error though. I return "Farmer" in the farmer class and "Person" in the person class. Since i store no instance of Person should it even implement Externalizable in the same way as the other classes? I also have an attribute which is the list of the fields the farmer has and which type is java.util.List <Field>.I have other specific classes objects attributes in both classes but all correctly registered.Do you Have any other idea why i might be running in such an issue?

Comment: Did you register both using the util class? Where did you put the registration code?

Comment: Yes i did register both classes with the Util class and the code is in the initVars mehod (it's a gui bluidler project)

Comment: The thing is when i write the objects to storage and in the same execution of the simulator, i try to read them it works just fine but when i close the simulator and launch it again, all classes objects are correctly fetched from storage expect the Farmer and Field classes objects

Comment: Try flushing the cache after writing to see if this still works in the same execution (there is a method for that in storage). Look in the console during read/write to see if an exception is printed.

Comment: I did flush the cache with the flushStorageCache method that i called on my instance of storage and it's still working in the same execution. I get all objects with the correct information inside the attributes. I have no exception during reading or writing from/to storage. I'm still having the first element of the list which is of type Field but the rest are.null or Date elements. I'm guessing it's using the attributes of one Field object as the elements of the list of Field objects because the date element is the value of a Date attribute in the Field class

Comment: Sorry I forgot there is a flush method too. I meant clearCache(). I suggest putting breakpoints into the externalization process and walking thru them to see what is written/read

Comment: I just tried clearCache () after writing and i can't fetch the data from storage anymore. Does that point you to a solution? I tried debug the externalization and the internalization process before. There are some null.values which are written but apart from that it seems to be working fine...i guess. Or are null values an issue?

Comment: If you write null using code like write UTF that could be a problem but it's surprising you don't see an exception in the console as those are printed out... I suggest posting the externalization/internalization code you used.

Comment: Hi shai. I posted the code as a second answer yesterday.

Comment: You need to press the edit button on your question and post the content there not as a second answer. Then comment as we don't get notices on edits... In the subclass you write double entries and read float entries which are incompatible. You should have gotten an overflow that should have resulted in an error. I also noticed you write the VERSION which is redundant since it's implicitly written and given to you during read.

Comment: Hi shai. The problem was coming from the type issue (float and double). I fixed it and It's working just fine now. Sorry for the delay in my answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! FYI when an answer is correct on stackoverflow you should check the V on the left side of the answer to mark it as such and you get points for accepting the answer. The points are valuable as they provide you with more privileges in the site...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the methods for the Person class

```
public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) {
            try {
                //Personne
                Util.writeUTF(getNomPersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getPrenomPersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getAdressePersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getLieuNaisPersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getPhotoPersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getSituationMatrimonialePersonne(), out);
                Util.writeUTF(getTelPersonne(), out);

                out.writeLong(getIdPersone() == null ? 0 : getIdPersone());
                out.writeInt(getVERSION() == null ? 0 : getVERSION() );
                out.writeChar(getSexePersonne());

                Util.writeObject(getDateNaisPersonne(), out);
                Util.writeObject(getLocalisationPersonne() , out);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Dialog.show("Erreur ","L'exception "+ex.getMessage(),"Ok",null);
            }
        }

    public void internalize(int version, DataInputStream in){
            try {
                nomPersonne = Util.readUTF(in);
                prenomPersonne = Util.readUTF(in);
                adressePersonne = Util.readUTF(in);
                lieuNaisPersonne =  Util.readUTF(in);
                photoPersonne = Util.readUTF(in);
                situationMatrimonialePersonne = Util.readUTF(in);
                telPersonne = Util.readUTF(in);

                idPersone = in.readLong();
                VERSION = in.readInt();
                sexePersonne = in.readChar();

                dateNaisPersonne = (Date) Util.readObject(in);
                localisationPersonne = (StructureAdministrative) Util.readObject(in);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                 Dialog.show("Erreur ","L'exception "+ex.getMessage(),"Ok",null);
            }
        }
```

An here come the methods for the farmer class which inherits from Person

```
@Override
    public void externalize(DataOutputStream out) {
        try {
            //Personne
            super.externalize(out);
            //Agriculteur
            Util.writeUTF(this.getNumPieceIdentite(), out);
            Util.writeUTF(this.getPhotoPieceIdentite(), out);
            Util.writeUTF(this.getPhotoPieceRecto(), out);
            Util.writeUTF(this.getPhotoPieceVerso(), out);
            Util.writeUTF(this.getTelAgripme(), out);

            out.writeInt(this.getNombreEnfant() == null ? 0 : this.getNombreEnfant()  );
            out.writeInt(getTailleMenage() == null ? 0 : getTailleMenage());
            out.writeDouble(getDistanceParcourue() == null ? 0 : getDistanceParcourue());
            out.writeDouble(getDureeAttente() == null ? 0 : getDureeAttente());
            out.writeBoolean(getaPiece() == null ? false : getaPiece());
            out.writeBoolean(getMembreCooperative() == null ? false : getMembreCooperative());
            out.writeInt(getParidPersone() == null ? 0 : getParidPersone());


            Util.writeObject(getDateExpirPiece(), out);
            Util.writeObject(getTypePieceIdentite(), out);
            Util.writeObject(getTypeProprieteFoncier() , out);
            Util.writeObject(getListeChamps(), out);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERREUR DE L'ECRITURE DES AGRICULTEUR EST"+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

@Override
public void internalize(int version, DataInputStream in)  {
    try {
        //Personne
        super.internalize(version, in);
        //Agriculteur
        numPieceIdentite = Util.readUTF(in);
        photoPieceIdentite = Util.readUTF(in);
        photoPieceRecto = Util.readUTF(in);
        photoPieceVerso = Util.readUTF(in);
        telAgripme = Util.readUTF(in);

        nombreEnfant = in.readInt();
        tailleMenage = in.readInt();
        distanceParcourue = in.readFloat();
        dureeAttente = in.readFloat();
        aPiece = in.readBoolean();
        membreCooperative = in.readBoolean();
        ParidPersone = in.readInt();


        dateExpirPiece = (Date) Util.readObject(in);
        typePieceIdentite = (TypePieceIdentite) Util.readObject(in);
        typeProprieteFoncier = (TypeProprieteFoncier) Util.readObject(in);
        listeChamps = (ArrayList<Champ>) Util.readObject(in);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("LA LECTURE DES AGRICULTEURS DE LA BASE A TEL PROBLÈME "+ ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```